# What does a battery produce? Is it Electric Potential Difference (EPD) or Electro Motive Force (EMF)?

Tags: electricity, potential, voltage, batteries, electrochemistry

I have read a lot of posts about Electro Motive Force, Electric Potential Difference  and their differences, but I still confused. What I know is that EMF produces a EPD and keeps it constant, then which one of the above puts the electrons into motion? In a battery does the chemical reaction produces electrons or does the chemical energy produces by it produce EMF which creates a EPD which in turn drives the electrons and produces current which when attached to a load results in various electrical phenomenon ? I know that EMF is some kind of energy but I still can't get any sort of clear picture. I definitely know that I'm wrong somewhere, please help.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that EMF is some kind of energy

No "emf" is not a kind of energy. The electro-motive force is an unfortunate historical term that represents *not* a force, but a potential difference in volts. So essentially, the emf of a battery is the *maximum potential difference* that can exist between it's terminals.

In simple cells like the Daniel Cell, *redox* reactions occur, and the chemical potential energy due to these reactions is used to maintain this potential difference throughout the battery, during it's lifetime.

> In a battery does the chemical reaction produces electrons?

No a battery does *not* supply electrons in a circuit

> Then which one of the above puts the electrons into motion?

Any charged particle moves under the influence of an external electric field. When there is a potential difference between two points, an electric field exists, that points in the direction of decreasing electric potential. Hence, when the battery sets a *terminal voltage* (potential difference) between its two terminals, charges (electrons) in the wires move in response to the electric field that it sets up in the wires. So in general you can say that a battery is a *source of constant emf* and a *source of energy* in an electric circuit.

Comment: I do not think that this is entirely correct. There is an important fundamental difference between potential difference and electromotive force. The former is a result of electrostatic and is conservative, while the latter is a result of a spontaneous chemical reaction (minimizing Gibbs free energy) and is not conservative. In other words, the force that drives electrons around a circuit is not electrostatic but chemical in nature.

Comment: @VincentThacker, I've read that the chemical energy in a cell is converted into electrostatic potential energy between cells, because the battery does work in separating the electrons produced in the reaction (hence the potential energy and consequent potential difference). As for whether or not the driving force is chemical or electical is actually quite interesting, but eitherway, the result is an electric field that exerts forces on the charges.

Comment: EMF is force acting on mobile charges per unit charge integrated over distance. It is not in general equal to potential difference, due to internal resistance. In a simple circuit with real battery resistance $R_i$ and load resistance $R$, electrochemical EMF $\mathscr{E}$ and current $I$ obey the equation $\mathscr{E} = R_i I + RI$, and potential difference on the battery is $ \mathscr{E} - R_iI$, thus not equal to EMF.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just start and think what an electric cell is.
It is a device in which a constant difference in potential* is maintained between the 2 electrodes/terminals by a chemical reaction.

Consider a Daniel Cell (Zn oxidised and Cu reduced)

Now look at the Zn electrode, placed in 1M Zn2+ electrolyte.
On the surface of the Zn electrode, there will be some ions near it from the electrolyte.
Now think, will there be a difference of potential between the ions and surface of electrode (one is charged, one isn’t)
The Zn atoms will want to escape to the solution , and to do so, they have to be oxidised (lose electrons.
But, when the cell isn’t connected to a closed circuit, there is nowhere the electrons liberated can go to. Hence, no current is drawn.
Similarly in the copper electrode, the the Cu2+ ions would want to join the Cu atoms in the electrode.
(Scientists have experimentally concluded that Cu would want to be reduced and zinc oxidised)
But there wouldn’t be a source of electrons to reduce the Cu ions.

When connected, the Zn can send the electrons to Cu, and both would be happy.
The chemical energy liberated from the reactions of oxidation and reduction is used to drive the electron across the 2 terminals.

Then the kinetic energy of the moving electrons is used to do some work for a device connected to a circuit.

The potential of the cell is defined as sum of oxidation and reduction potential of the 2 electrodes

You need this kind of force to move them from higher potential to lower ones in order to complete a cycle. This force could be chemical, magnetic or even electric (vortex electric field, different from electrostatic field), and their equivalent contribution is called electromotive force. (which isn’t a force, mind me, it’s just the difference in potential of the cell)

So yes, a cell produces a difference in potential, and it’s called EMF.

Hope I answer the “from where do the electrons come from” part of the answer.

Hope my answer helps,
A sincere 11th grader.